# Problema ao mostrar/ocultar divs ao subir site

Tags: jquery, div

Olá, estou utilizando JQuery para mostrar/ocultar as divs. Quando abro a página local as divs funcionam normalmente (abrem e escondem), porém ao subir a página para a web (realizar a hospedagem), as divs não funcionam mais.
Já olhei no inspecionar e não está mostrando nenhum erro. Minha dúvida é, o que pode estar ocasionando esse erro? E se possível, me ajudarem com uma forma mais funcional de fazer isso? Desde já agradeço.

É esse o código que estou usando:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <meta name = "viewport" content = "width:device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Mostrar/Ocultar</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src='lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class = "Menu-Lateral">
 <div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <nav class = "menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class = "conteudoDiv" data-element = "#carimbo"><i class = "fa fa-certificate"></i>Solicitar Carimbo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class = "conteudoDiv" data-element = "#auditorio"><i class = "fa fa-tty"></i>Portaria</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id = "carimbo" class = "row">
 <h1>Carimbo</h1>
</div>

<div id = "auditorio" class = "row">
 <h1>Auditorio</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#carimbo
{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: none;
}

#auditorio
{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ocultar()
{
  document.getElementById('carimbo').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('auditorio').style.display = 'none';
}

</script>

<!-- Controle das divs !-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  $('.conteudoDiv').on('click', function(e)
  {
    ocultar();
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).slideToggle('slow');
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Uai jovem, cade o link de indexação do jQuery na sua página??

Comment: Estou usando link CDN (<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>)

Comment: Ah, agora que vc editou tudo bem...! Mas vc deveria usar uma verão mais nova tipo a 3.1 ou 3.2... não que isso vá resolver o problema com certeza, mas é uma boa prática usar as versões mais novas se não afetar seu script

Comment: Entendi, vou trocar por uma versão mais atualizada. Obrigado pela dica!!

Comment: Qual é a versão do Bootstrap que vc está usando?

Comment: Por favor, passe o link da sua página que está dando problema na internet

Comment: Confere na Aba "Network" do Chrome DevTools se todos os arquivos .JS estão sendo carregados na página

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Muito obrigado!! 
Estava ocorrendo um conflito em um dos trechos do código.
Estou usando a versão 4.0.0 do Bootstrap
Aqui está o link: http://www.garotodati.com.br/divsMostrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem muita redundância, começando pelo CSS: se as `id`s são exatamente iguais, você não precisa repetir separados, pode declarar as duas ao mesmo tempo. E também não precisa setar `width: 100%` e `margin: 0 auto` já que a `div` ocupa toda a largura de onde está, além do mais você já está centralizando o texto com `text-align: center;`. Então ficaria apenas assim:

```
#carimbo, #auditorio{
   text-align: center;
   display: none;
}
```

Outra coisa desnecessária é essa função `ocultar()`. Além do que você mistura JavaScript puro usando `document.getElementById('carimbo').style.display = 'none';` quando poderia apenas usar o método `.hide()` do jQuery com os dois `id`s ao mesmo tempo como seletor, e pode fazer isso dentro do próprio evento `.click` sem a necessidade de chamar outra função só para fazer isso.

```
$('#carimbo, #auditorio').hide();
```

Seu código otimizado fica assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.conteudoDiv').on('click', function(e){
      $('#carimbo, #auditorio').hide();
      e.preventDefault();
      var el = $(this).data('element');
      $(el).slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
#carimbo, #auditorio{
   text-align: center;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class = "Menu-Lateral">
 <div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <nav class = "menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class = "conteudoDiv" data-element = "#carimbo"><i class = "fa fa-certificate"></i>Solicitar Carimbo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class = "conteudoDiv" data-element = "#auditorio"><i class = "fa fa-tty"></i>Portaria</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id = "carimbo" class = "row">
   <h1>Carimbo</h1>
</div>
<div id = "auditorio" class = "row">
   <h1>Auditorio</h1>
</div>
```

> Também não precisa declarar o `type="text/javascript"` do script. Isso
>   já não é mais necessário no HTML5.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pelas dicas!!